# Destroying an object with ongoing function call

Tags: c++, boost, mutex, shared-ptr

Assume I have class A with resource B. Class A has a function that does not acquire a mutex lock before I want to destroy it. I call boost::shared_ptr::reset() to destroy instance of class A. Is resource B guaranteed to be destroyed at that point?

```
class Resource{
public:
    Resource(){ }
    ~Resource(){ free(); }
    void init() {}
    void free() {}  
};

class A{
public:
    A(){ B.init(); }
    ~A(){}

    void functionC(){
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(Mutex);
        // Stuck forever
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock2(Mutex);
    }
private:
    boost::mutex Mutex;
    Resource B;
};

main(){
    boost::shared_ptr<A> pointer(new A());

    // Do a function call that gets stuck but allows main thread to continue
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&A::functionC, *pointer));

    pointer.reset();

    // Loop forever
    while(1);
}
```

To be specific, I want function B::free() to be called at the point in which I call pointer.reset(). Is this code guaranteed to do that, or do I have to explicitly call it somewhere? Obviously I don't want to be as explicit as

```
pointer->freeB();
pointer.reset();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, B is a member of A.  It will get destroyed (and `free()` will be called) when A gets destroyed.  No need for an explicit call.

However in your code, there's no guarantee that your `pointer.reset()` the allocated A object gets destroyed: it only gets destroyed if `pointer` was the only `shared_ptr` pointing to this object, i.e. no copy of the pointer was made since its creation (there 's no evidence of that here, but to be checked in your real code).

By the way,  there's a `t.join()` missing in your code.